# can "today" be used for present, past and future?

Tags: word-usage

See these 3 sentences:

> I bought it today.
>
> I will buy it today
>
> I am working today.

I am not sure I can say like that.

So, can "today" be used for present, past and future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problems using it in all three tenses.

Examples:

> — Nice car! When did you buy it?
>   — I **bought** it **today**.
>   — You like the computer?
>   — Yeah.
>   — So, when are you gonna buy it? Today or tomorrow?
>   — I think I'll **buy** it **today**.
>   — We're going to the cinema. Are you going to join us?
>   — Sorry, I can't. I'm **working today**.

You may be thinking that since the word *today* specifically refers to the present, it can't be used in reference to things that can happen or have happened sometime in the future or the past. But, you'd be wrong. It's just an adverb. Within 24 hours, there is plenty of room for the past, present and future.

Comment: *Today* when used with future tense means "some time before this day ends," and when used with past tense it means "before now but not before this day started."